# Auto run code when Android starts up?

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I want my code will run automatically when the android starts up.And,i know that the init.rc srcipt will be runned when the android starts up.So,i decided to add my code's information as the service item in the init.rc.But unfortunately, it fails.
Below are the steps that I used:
1. I build the server.c via the ndk's cross-compiler:
server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    void sys_log(char* msg) {

        FILE *fp;
        time_t t;

        if((fp=fopen("/data/server.log","a")) >=0)
        {
            t=time(0);
            fprintf(fp,"%s at time: %s\n", msg, asctime(localtime(&t)) );

        }
        fclose(fp);
    }


    int main() {
        printf("server begin!");
        sys_log("server begin!");
    )
```

1. I add the following lines to the end of /init.rc:

   service socketserver /data/server
       oneshot
2. I restart the android device
3. I use the instruction `cat /data/server.log` to check the log, but there is nothing in the server.log!
4. I run the server directly. Everything runs okay. Both the log and the console will prompt what i want!

So in conclusion, I think the init.rc does not start the server that I built.
Are my steps correct? Any ideas? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: your question is somewhat unclear. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank u for suggestion.And,I have aready rewrited it!

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't want to use a BootReceiver to get a callback? That API is specifically meant to handle what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank u ,Tim.Because my code is writed in native code,c language.So,i think it is not convient to use the BootReceiver.And,what i want to do is just to test whether the code have been started up.